# When and why are units measured in degree?

Tags: energy, temperature, conventions, units, metrology

I was always under the impression that a unit is measured in degree if it is a relative unit. While this is true for temperatures and angles, I cannot find any reference to this definition or any other proper definition. When thumbing through textbooks, all I can find is "such, and such quantity is measured in degree '°'" without any reason given.

Comment: Units just give you a reference for physical quantities to be measured with respect to. The usage of the units "degrees" is no different to the usage of the units "kilograms", it's just a unit.

Comment: I don't think there are any examples other than the degrees used for angles and degrees C. So the rule is that it is used in those two cases and nowhere else.

Comment: Temperature is measured in Kelvins, angles are measured in radians.

Answer (score 1):

In some ways this is not a question about Physics rather one needs to look at the etymology of the word *degree*. Latin *degradus "a step", and so the notion of "one of a number of subdivisions of something".  As to the angle measure it is a legacy of counting to base $60$, sexagesimal, by the ancient Sumerians in the 3rd millennium BC which was then passed down to the ancient Babylonians.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the temperature, the units measured in degrees are referring to something periodic (for example, the phase of oscillations), which can then be reduced to angle, and consequently measured in degrees ($1/360$ of the full circle), grads ($1/400$ of the full circle) or radians. Angles are obviously dimensionless.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that originally the degree was the nightly shift in the position of the stars in the sky,  but as with the original defnition of the meter, they didn't get it quite right. Or, mabe someone later decided to round it so that number of degrees in a circle could be factored.